# android createTempFile throws permission denied?

Tags: android, file-io, permissions, permission-denied

This is simple, but not working.  I am trying to create a temp file (later a permanent storage file) for preview of an MP3 file.  I have tried the following variants of the suffix as  following example:

```
public class StudyFileIo extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "StudyFileIo";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        try {
            File tempFooFile = File
            .createTempFile("foo", "dat");
            Log.i(TAG, tempFooFile.getAbsolutePath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Log:

```
09-07 11:25:20.299 E/StudyFileIo( 8859): java.io.IOException: Permission denied
09-07 11:25:20.299 W/System.err( 8859): java.io.IOException: Permission denied
09-07 11:25:20.299 W/System.err( 8859):     at java.io.File.createNewFileImpl(Native Method)
09-07 11:25:20.299 W/System.err( 8859):     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1160)
09-07 11:25:20.299 W/System.err( 8859):     at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1224)
09-07 11:25:20.299 W/System.err( 8859):     at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1182)
09-07 11:25:20.299 W/System.err( 8859):     at com.mobibob.studyfileio.StudyFileIo.onCreate(StudyFileIo.java:25)
09-07 11:25:20.299 W/System.err( 8859):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-07 11:25:20.299 W/System.err( 8859):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
09-07 11:25:20.309 W/System.err( 8859):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
09-07 11:25:20.309 W/System.err( 8859):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-07 11:25:20.309 W/System.err( 8859):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
09-07 11:25:20.309 W/System.err( 8859):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-07 11:25:20.309 W/System.err( 8859):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-07 11:25:20.309 W/System.err( 8859):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-07 11:25:20.309 W/System.err( 8859):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-07 11:25:20.309 W/System.err( 8859):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-07 11:25:20.319 W/System.err( 8859):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:876)
09-07 11:25:20.319 W/System.err( 8859):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:634)
09-07 11:25:20.319 W/System.err( 8859):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is there some AndroidManifest.xml setting that I am missing (I am using default manifest)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to create the temp files in a directory that your application owns. You should use [`createTempFile(String prefix, String suffix, File directory)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File)), where *directory* is the location to which the temp file is to be written. You can get a valid location for *directory* with the result from [`Context.getFilesDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()) or [`Context.getDir(String name, int mode)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDir(java.lang.String,%20int)).

Comment: Thanks Marc.  I had tried the form with the directory, but I was still supplying a directory that I did not have access to, getCacheDirectory.  Your suggestion worked.  Meanwhile, I switched to getBaseContext().openFileOutput(...)

Answer (score 14):

I think that you just missed the permission to write at the external storage, since temp files are created there by default.
Add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

to your manifest and it should work.

Comment: This is right if you try to write to external storage but for OP, this is not the case.

Comment: According to [the Android docs](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath), you still need this permission in version 18 and below.  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="18" />`

Answer (score 5):

Even after adding
**<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"** this to manifest I was getting error.
But after adding this
**android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"**
in application tag of manifest file I am able to createTempFile and able capture pic from phone.

**<application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"**

Comment: after I add that line it wont compile saying error: failed processing manifest.

Comment: if you faced this error, and found that the error occured only on old android version device. this is the correct answer one.