# Which cache directory is the proper one to store temporary images?

Tags: android

For my Android app, i have to download image from server and i am keeping it in internal cache directory (or External cache directory if it is available then). Sometimes some of my users phones gets crashed because of

`context.getExternalCacheDir() returns null`

So I planned to use default cache directory (ie internal) for this purpose. So my question is whether is there any chance for

```
context.getCacheDir() returns null?
```

If it is there, what is the best way to store some cache images without using Storage Permission?

Comment: You can use https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader library to fetch images from internet. the images can be cached on disk, or memory

Comment: How about picasso

Comment: Check the comparison chart among the famous libraries here
http://stackoverflow.com/a/29677374/2116420

Answer (score 0):

**`context.getCacheDir()`**

> Returns the absolute path to the directory on the filesystem where
>   files created it will may change with time it will not null becuase its the path where your app exists.

Use [**File createTempFile (String prefix, 
                String suffix, 
                File directory)**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File))

If you want to do it with runtime permssion use third param with you internal memmory path `Context.getFilesDir()` or `Context.getDir(String name, int mode).`

[**Source here.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660572/android-createtempfile-throws-permission-denied)