# java.io.IOException: Permission denied for createNewFile()

Tags: java, android, file

I am trying to create a file in the external storage. I have added the permission in manifest file and also added checkPermission function before calling `createNewFile()` function. But I am still getting Permission Denied error.

**Manifest file**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>     
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

**Java Code**

```
final File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
final String fileName = activity.getString(R.string.app_name) + (new Date().getTime()) + ".pdf";
File file = new File(path, fileName);
System.out.println("Creating file with name - "+fileName);
try {
   checkPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 101);
   file.createNewFile();
   System.out.println("Successfully created file with name - "+fileName);
} 
catch (Exception e) {
   Log.e("TAG", "Failed to open ParcelFileDescriptor", e);
}
```

```
public  void checkPermission(String permission, int requestCode)
{
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.activity, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions( this.activity, new String[] { permission }, requestCode);
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this.activity, "Permission already granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**Error Trace**

```
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:317)
        at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1008)
        at in.justnow.aryan.JsInterface$6.run(JsInterface.java:636)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7397)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
```

Comment: Does this also happen while debugging?

Comment: Yes, @AdityaKurkure.

Comment: Your phone running Android 10 right ?

Comment: Yes @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI

Comment: Hello you can check this link ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660572/android-createtempfile-throws-permission-denied

Comment: Problem is that with each next android release file access become harder, and harder - look here https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage

Comment: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58625949/how-to-get-access-to-external-storage-in-android-10-android-q

Comment: The `requestPermissions()` method is asynchronous. That is, your code does not stop and wait while the permissions dialog shows. It continues immediately on to the next line, where the `file.createNewFile();` line is running way before the user could have possibly granted the permission. You need to wait until `onRequestPermissionsResult()` to check whether the permission is granted, and then do your file access, if allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your PDF file using the following code :

```
  final String fileName = getString(R.string.app_name) + (new Date().getTime()) + ".pdf";
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
            String filePath = PathUtils.getExternalAppDownloadPath().concat("/").concat(fileName);
            boolean isSuccess = FileUtils.createOrExistsFile(filePath);
            if (isSuccess) System.out.println("Successfully created file with name - " + fileName);
            else System.out.println("Something went wrong!");
        } else {
            String filePath = PathUtils.getExternalDownloadsPath().concat("/").concat(fileName);
            boolean isSuccess = FileUtils.createOrExistsFile(filePath);
            if (isSuccess) System.out.println("Successfully created file with name - " + fileName);
            else System.out.println("Something went wrong!");
        }
```

The used library : `implementation 'com.blankj:utilcodex:1.29.0'`

**OR**

(**Not recommended**) use :  `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` inside the Application Tag in your `AndroidManifest.XML`